# weak sequential continuity of linear operators

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose I have a weakly sequentially continuous linear operator T between two normed linear spaces X and Y (i.e. $x_n \stackrel {w}{\rightharpoonup} x$ in $X$ $\Rightarrow$ $T(x_n) \stackrel {w}{\rightharpoonup} T(x)$ in $Y$). Does this imply that my operator T must be bounded?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In my original answer I only mentioned that it works for $Y$ complete, but as Nate pointed out in a comment, I never actually used completeness of $Y$.

The answer is yes. Weakly convergent sequences in a normed space are bounded, as a consequence of the uniform boundedness principle applied to the dual space (which is a Banach space) and the fact that a convergent sequence of real (or complex) numbers is bounded. If $T$ is unbounded, then there is a sequence $x_1,x_2,\ldots$ in $X$ converging in norm (and hence weakly) to 0 such that $\|T(x_n)\|\to\infty$, so by the previous sentence this implies that $T(x_1),T(x_2),\ldots$ does not converge weakly.

Comment: You don't need $Y$ to be complete; if you check, you are applying the uniform boundedness principle in $Y^*$ which is a Banach space regardless.

Comment: Looking back at this, it's more obvious than I realized that this answer has nothing to do with $Y$ being complete, because weak convergence and boundedness obviously are independent of being complete.

Comment: @JonasMeyer : is it not that $T(x_n)$ is in double dual of $X$ ? I am quite confused here . $x_n$ are in $X$, and as operator $T(x_n)$ takes value from $X'$ say $f$and gives me a value $f(x_n)$. What is my misunderstanding here ?

Comment: @Theorem: $T:X\to Y$, as in says in the question.

Comment: It is a long time since you posted that answer, but I would like to ask you something. Why the assumption of unboundedness of the operator $T$ (or equivalently not continuous at $0$ ) implies the existence of such a sequence $x_n\to 0$ such that $\|Tx_n\|\to\infty$ > Isn't it that there exists a sequence $x_n\to 0$ in norm and some $\epsilon>0$ such that $\|Tx_n\|\ge \epsilon,\,\forall n\in\mathbb N$ ?

Comment: @Svetoslav: Unboundedness of T implies that for each $M>0$ there exists x with norm 1 such that $\|Tx\|>M$.  Thus for each positive integer n take $y_n$ with norm 1 such that $\|Ty_n\|>n^2$, and take $x_n=\frac1n y_n$.