# When is an operator between two Banach spaces the adjoint of another operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Weak-to-weak continuous operator which is not norm-continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55679/weak-to-weak-continuous-operator-which-is-not-norm-continuous)

I saw in some text that if an operator $T:Y^\star \rightarrow X^\star$ (where $X$ and $Y$ are separable Banach spaces) is $w^\star - w^\star$ - continuous then $T$ is the adjoint of some operator $S:X\rightarrow Y$. Can anyone write a short proof for this claim or give some reference?

Comment: See part b) of the answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/q/55679

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. It is true that the answer is in that question, but will anybody who is looking for this find the answer? If I search the site using the title of this question as my search string, the answers mentioned in the comments do not appear, at least not in the first page.

Comment: @Martin: Anybody searching for this title will find this question, which has a perfectly good link to the previous one.