# Is every operator in $B(X^*)$ the adjoint of some operator in $B(X)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, adjoint-operators, dual-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $A\in B(X^*)$. I want to know if there exists some operator $B\in B(X)$ such that $B^*=A$, that is if the "adjoint" operation in surjective.
Thank you !

Comment: In general, no.  If $X$ is reflexive, yes.  Perhaps you can find an example of an operator on $l^1$ that is not the dual of any operator on $c_0$, even though $c_0^* = l^1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A = B^*$ for some $B$ if and only if $A$ is continuous in the weak-* topology.  See e.g. the answer to  [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55679/weak-to-weak-continuous-operator-which-is-not-norm-continuous).  One of the comments there gives an example of an $A$ that is not continuous in the weak-* topology.