# On linear operators on Tempered Distributions

Tags: linear-transformations, schwartz-space

Consider $\mathscr{S}$ the Schwartz space of rapidly decreasing complex smooth functions over $\mathbb{R}^{d} $, equipped with its usual metric topology, and S′ its topological dual, the space of tempered distributions.

If $\mathcal{L} : \mathscr{S} \to \mathscr{S}$ is a linear and continuous operator, one can define its adjoint $\mathcal{L}^{*} : \mathscr{S}' \to \mathscr{S}'$ as the linear operator such that for every tempered distribution $T \in \mathscr{S}'$, it defines the distribution $ \mathcal{L}^{*}(T) = T \circ \mathcal{L} $, that is,
$$ \langle \mathcal{L}^{*}(T) , \varphi \rangle = \langle T , \mathcal{L}(\varphi) \rangle, \quad \forall \varphi \in \mathscr{S}, T \in \mathscr{S}'. \tag{1}\label{1}$$

It is easy to prove that $\mathcal{L}^{*}$ so defined is continuous when $\mathscr{S}'$ is equipped with the weak-$*$ topology.  Within this framework, I have two questions:

1. Is $\mathcal{L}^{*}$ also continuous when $\mathscr{S}'$ is equipped with the strong topology?
2. If $\mathcal{L}^{*} : \mathscr{S}' \to \mathscr{S}'$ is a linear operator which is continuous when $\mathscr{S}'$ is equipped with the weak-$*$ topology, does it exist a linear operator $\mathcal{L} : \mathscr{S} \to \mathscr{S}$, continuous with respect to the metric topology on $\mathscr{S}$, such that $\eqref{1}$ holds? (that is, does it exist a "pre-adjoint" operator?)

I've tried to work out this questions using the reflexivity property $ (\mathscr{S}')'=\mathscr{S}$, but this property is known to be truth for the strong topology on $\mathscr{S}'$ and not necessarily when using the weak-$*$ topology (I've made another post with this precise question).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think that you have missed a prime sign at the end of $\mathcal{L}^{*} : \mathscr{S}' \to \mathscr{S}$.

Comment: What is the strong topology on $\mathscr S'$?

Comment: Corrected, thanks. The strong topology is a notion I actually have some trouble understanding its implications. It is the topology induced by the family of seminorms definied by $p_{B}(T) = \sup_{\varphi \in B}|\langle T , \varphi \rangle | $, whit $B$ describing the bounded sets of $\mathscr{S}$. Thus, a net of tempered distributions $(T_{n})_{n}$ is convergent to $0$ in the strong topology if it converges to $0$ uniformly over bounded sets of $\mathscr{S}$.

Comment: 1 is definitely true but I don't know about 2, I would suspect not. The right topology to use for $\mathscr{S}'$ is the strong topology. The weak-$\ast$ is quite pathological.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes: $$\sup_{\|T\|\leq1}{\|\mathcal{L}^*T\|}=\sup_{\|T\|\leq1,\|\phi\|\leq1}{(\mathcal{L}^*T)(\phi)}=\sup_{\|T\|\leq1,\|\phi\|\leq1}{T(\mathcal{L}\phi)}\leq\|\mathcal{L}\|$$
2. Also yes; see [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55679/weak-to-weak-continuous-operator-which-is-not-norm-continuous) or Exercise 3.10 in Brezis, *Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces, and PDE* (2011).

Comment: The spaces in play are not Banach