# Bounded linear function with no predual

Tags: functional-analysis, dual-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces, and let $S$ be any bounded linear function between the dual spaces of $Y$ and $X$, i.e. $S: Y^* \to X^*$. I need to come up with some $S$ such that it is not the predual of any bounded linear function $T: X \to Y$.

I have seen this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1832836/a-linear-map-sy-to-x-is-weak-continuous-if-and-only-if-s-t-for-so) about it. Here it proves that $S$ will only have some $T$ as a predual if and only if it is weak* continuous. I do not understand this concept and in my class we have not discussed it, so I guess it is not neccessarry to find such an example.

Can anybody suggest some functions? Thanks!

Comment: see also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55679/weak-to-weak-continuous-operator-which-is-not-norm-continuous

Answer (score 1):

Take $X=Y=c_0$, $X^*=Y^*=l^1$. Define
$$
S(x) = (\sum x_n) e_1,
$$
where $e_1$ is the unit vector $(1,0,0,\dots)$. $S$ is clearly bounded. It is not weak-star continuous: $Se_k = e_1$ for all $k$
but $e_k \rightharpoonup^* 0$ in $l^1=(c_0)^*$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you maybe show there is no $T$ such that $T^*=S$ without using the notion of weak* continuity?