# Weak $W^{k,p}$-convergence implies weak $W^{m,p}$ convergence of the $\nabla^{k-m}$-sequence

Tags: sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence, weak-derivatives

I have the following question: given $m$, $p$, and $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ bounded or unbounded, if the sequence
$$u_i \rightharpoonup u$$
weakly in $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$, then is it true that 
$$\nabla^{k-m}u_i \rightharpoonup \nabla^{k-m}u$$
weakly in $W^{m,p}(\Omega)$ with the convention
$$
\nabla^q =
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
& \Delta^{q/2} & & \text{ if } \; q \; \text{ is even},\\
& \nabla\Delta^{(q-1)/2} & & \text{ if } \; q \; \text{ is odd}.
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

A particular case of this question is the following: if $u_i \rightharpoonup u$ weakly in $H^1(\Omega)$, then $\nabla u_i \rightharpoonup \nabla u$ weakly in $L^2(\Omega)$. I believe that the answer is positive.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is true. Taking the weak derivative is a bounded and linear operation, hence it is weakly continuous (weak-weak continuous). E.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/729881/weak-convergence-of-a-bounded-linear-operator?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Take $\nabla^{k-m} : W^{k,p} \to W^{m,p}$, linearity is clear and boundedness follows from $\|\nabla^{k-m}u\|_{W^{m,p}} \leq \|u\|_{W^{k,p}}$ (on the right side are just more terms).

Hence, from $u_m \rightharpoonup u$ in $W^{k,p}$ it follows $\nabla^{k-m}u \rightharpoonup \nabla^{k-m} u$ in  $W^{m,p}$.