# Weakly sequentially continuous operators in Hilbert space are norm continuous.

Tags: hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

Suppose I have a linear operator T from a Hilbert space H to itself, and T maps every weak convergent sequence to a weak convergent sequence. Show that T is continuous.

I feel that this statement will not be true for general Banach spaces. Weak convergence in a Hilbert space means the inner product of Xn and u converges to the inner product of X and u for any u in H. But I don't see how it helps me in proving the claim. And I think closed graph theorem will not help either, since the assumption is about strong convergence.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5795/weak-sequential-continuity-of-linear-operators).

Comment: Edited title to be search friendly.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

1. Try proving the contrapositive.  If $T$ is not continuous, show that it maps some bounded sequence $\{x_n\}$ to a sequence $\{T x_n\}$ with $\|T x_n\| \to \infty$.  Passing to a subsequence and rescaling, we can even assume $\|x_n\| \to 0$, and in particular $x_n \to 0$ weakly.
2. Every weakly convergent sequence is bounded.  (This comes from the uniform boundedness principle.)
3. Conclude that if $T$ is not continuous, it maps some weakly convergent sequence to a weakly non-convergent sequence.

Comment: Thank you Nate! I saw the proof of the step 2 this morning in the setting of Hilbert space. Do you suggest that it's not true in a general Banach space?

Comment: Hi David, I don't see why we can set Xn goes to 0

Comment: @DavidMitra: You are quite right, and in fact that makes the former step 2 unnecessary.

Comment: @SoWaiChung: It's no longer relevant to this question, but in fact it is not true in general that a bounded sequence in a Banach space has a weakly convergent subsequence.

Comment: By contradiction, assume T maps a bounded set to a unbounded set, therefore, we have a sequence |Xn|<=M,while |TXn|>n, now if you want Xn go to zero, you can divide Xn by a large number, but that will hurt |TXn| also, say this number is n, we only get |TXn|>1 which might not go to infinity.

Comment: @SoWaiChung Start with all $x_n$ of norm $1$. Choose $x_{n_k}$ with $\Vert Tx_{n_k}\Vert\ge k^2$.  Divide by $k$...

Comment: That works, thank you.