# Continuous Strong-Strong Implies Continuous Weak-Weak

Tags: general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis, self-learning, banach-spaces

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be two Banach spaces and let $T$ be a linear map between $X$ and $Y$. Show that $T$ is continuous strong-strong if and only if $T$ is continuous weak-weak.

1. I can see that $T$ being continuous strong-strong implies that $T$ is continuous strong-weak. How to see weak-weak, please?
2. I have no idea on the other direction. Could anyone help me, please? Thank you!

Comment: Hint: Assume it's weak-weak but not strong-strong. Then follow a proof by contradiction.

Comment: @Axoren Could add more detail, please?

Comment: You have to use the adjoint of the operator$T$.

Comment: For weak-weak implying strong-strong see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5795/weak-sequential-continuity-of-linear-operators