# Suppose that $ T$ is a linear operator from a normed space $ X $ into normed space $ Y $.Prove that the following are equivalent

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose that $T$ is a linear operator from a normed linear space $ X $ into normed linear space $ Y $.Prove that the following are equivalent.

$1)$ The operator $T$ is continuous.

$2)$The set $ T(K)$ is a weakly compact subset of $Y$ whenever $K$ is a weakly compact subset of $X$.

1) to 2) is clear but 2) to 1)??

Comment: The  answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5795/weak-sequential-continuity-of-linear-operators) may help.

Comment: You could add iii: $T(K)$ is bounded for every compact subset of $X$. Since weakly compact sets are bounded, ii implies iii which gives i because you only have to prove that images of null sequences are bounded.