# Characterization of boundedness of a linear operator under compactness

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

The following is an exercise from *An Introduction to Banach Space Theory* by *Robert E. Megginson*.

> Suppose that $T$ is a linear operator from a normed space $X$ into a normed space $Y$. Prove that the following are equivalent.
>
> a) The operator $T$ is continuous.
>
> b) The set $T(K)$ is a compact subset of $Y$ whenever $K$ is a compact subset of $X$.
>
> c) The set $T(K)$ is a weakly compact subset of $Y$ whenever $K$ is a weakly compact subset of $X$.

The idea that I have is that, to prove that b) implies a), let $x_{n}\rightarrow 0$, and consider the sequentially compact set $K=\{x_{n}:n=1,2,...\}\cup\{0\}$, then $K$ is also compact, and hence $T(K)=\{T(x_{n}):n=1,2,...\}\cup\{0\}$ is sequentially compact, it seems that we cannot say immediately that $T(x_{n})\rightarrow 0$, this is where I got stuck.

To prove that a) and c) are equivalent, I have only the idea that norm-to-norm continuous is equivalent to weak-to-weak continuous, but what can I do next?

The space $X$ has no approximate property, so one cannot use some sort of approximated by compact operators to argue this exercise.

**Edit:**

Part of the answer has been addressed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5795/weak-sequential-continuity-of-linear-operators). That is, by Mazur compactness theorem, weakly compact is equivalent to weakly sequentially compact, so the statement c) can be rephrased as the following one.

> The set $T(K)$ is sequentially compact subset of $Y$ whenever $K$ is a weakly sequentially compact.

To show that c) implies a). Assume that some sequence $\{x_{n}\}$ is such that $x_{n}\rightarrow 0$ but $\|T(x_{n})\|\rightarrow\infty$, then the set $K=\{x_{n}:n=1,2,...\}\cup\{0\}$ is weakly sequentially compact which implies by assumption that $T(K)=\{T(x_{n}): n=1,2,...\}\cup\{0\}$ is also weakly sequentially compact. In particular, the sequence $\{T(x_{n})\}$ has a weakly convergent sequence and hence the subsequence is bounded, this contradicts that $\|T(x_{n})\|\rightarrow\infty$.

In the same fashion, one proves that b) implies a).

To show that a) implies c). As I have said, $T$ is weak-tp-weak continuous. Assume that $K$ is a weakly compact subset of $X$ but $T(K)$ is not, then by sequential characterization again, one finds some sequence $\{T(x_{n})\}$ such that $T(x_{n})$ has no weakly convergent subsequence, where $\{x_{n}\}\subseteq K$. But $\{x_{n}\}$ has a weakly convergent subsequence, say, $\{x_{n_{k}}\}$, then by weak-to-weak continuity of $T$, $\{T(x_{n_{k}})\}$ is weakly convergent, this is a contradiction.

In the same fashion, one proves that a) implies b).

Comment: What's the problem with $T(x_n) \to 0$? If you assume $T$ to be continous and $x_n \to 0$ then you get $T(x_n) \to 0$.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the wrong a) and b).

Comment: Anyway, it seems that I have figured out the solution.

Comment: Yes it's not necessary to show that $Tx_n \to 0$, it sufficies to show that $Tx_n$ is bounded.

Answer (score 2):

Proof of b) implies a): if $T$ is not continuous there exists $\{y_n\}$ such that $\|Ty_n\| >n^{2}\|y_n\|$. Let $x_n =\frac {y_n} {n \|y_n\|}$. Then $x_n \to 0$ and $\|T(x_n)\|>n$. Hence $\{0,x_1,x_2,\cdots\}$ is a compact set whose image is not bounded.